# Unable To Run Speechrecognizer Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I seem to be not be able to run the speech recognizer on my phone. The app instals and the  button is returning what it needs to be returning but the actual voice recognizer isn't returning onBeginning of Speech and etc... Here is my code, hopefully it's an easy fix. I am running on a Galaxy s3 which displays the erros (Trace: Can't open, no such directory) and ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front. May be a problem with permissions. Any help would be great!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ListView lv;
private SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
private Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
    Button b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    boolean available = SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this);
    Log.d("Speech", "available = " + available);
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechListener());
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
            this.getPackageName());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("speech", "button active");
    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);


}
private class SpeechListener implements RecognitionListener {


    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.d("Speech", "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.d("Speech", "onBufferReceived");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.d("Speech", "onEndOfSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        Log.d("Speech", "onError");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        Log.d("Speech", "onEvent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        Log.d("Speech", "onPartialResults");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        Log.d("Speech", "onReadyForSpeech");
    }


    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.d("Speech", "results");

    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        //Log.d("Speech", "onRmsChanged");
    }

}
```

}

Here is my Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/> 

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.speech.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the version of the OS? ICS or JB? also post your manifest

Comment: The user permission was added, unfortunately still not receiving any way of voice input. I'm still getting those errors. I have no clue what is happening right now. Really just need help on this one badly.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still not getting the 
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
   Log.d("Speech", "onBeginningOfSpeech");
  } To show that the action is starting. I am updating my code to what I have so far.

Comment: You speak right away after clicking the button?

Comment: Pretty much.... I wonder the differences if I run it on a different device? How do you suggest going about that? What devices (budget) will be best for using with eclipse?

Comment: It works on mine Nexus S with JB 4.1. Edit your post to post the change code

Comment: I edited the post, copy and run it. If it works you will get an error when exit, will fix that later.

Comment: Ok, what did you edit? What post? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Your post above. I added code to check if speech recognizer is available and add permission in manifest.

Comment: Everything seems to be working. I understand the additions. I am getting an error where the method isRecognitionAvailable in the type SpeechRecognizer is not applicable for the arguments ()
I understand this but because I didn't write it I'm not fully sure the litteral intention to this. Maybe give me a pointer?

Comment: I fixed the error, I forgot to put in the context.

Comment: Hells YES!!!!! I'm getting logged Button active, OnReadyForSpeach, OnBeginningof Speech onEnOfSpeech and results!! This is just amazing! Wow!

Comment: On JB if you do not speak after 5 seconds, the speech recognizer is dead. There is a fix if it is a service, I do not know if it works for activity. But I am tired today, if there is problem make another post tomorrow and see if we can fix it.

Comment: Of course, I would like the end result of the app to allow the user to wait for a little bit longer.

Comment: Just play around for now, wait like 10 seconds before you speak and see if there is any error. If there is error make another post tomorrow and see if it is fixable. I am not quite sure yet how to fix for activity.

Comment: New post regarding waiting a little with the recognizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

And fix the following error instead of

```
protected class mSpeechRecognizerIntent implements RecognitionListener
```

it should be

```
private class SpeechListener implements RecognitionListener
```

and add the following in `onCreate` after the line

```
boolean available = SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable();
Log.d("Speech", "available = " + available);
mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechListener());
```